# Unable to use virtualenv and virtuenvwrapper on Ubuntu 20

Tags: command-line, 20.04, python3, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I am using Python3.7 and following the `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` installation as mentioned on [this FreeCodeCamp article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/virtualenv-with-virtualenvwrapper-on-ubuntu-18-04/).

The changes to my `.bashrc` file look as follows:

```bsh
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# popo edit: Add Python alias
alias python=python3

# popo edit: Step to activate virtualenvs
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
# SOme more things....

#Virtualenvwrapper settings:
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/home/pra-dan/.local/bin/virtualenv
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

On sourcing the `.bashrc`, I get

```
/usr/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3 and that PATH is
set properly.
```

ALthough, I managed to make an environment (idk how) and on typing `workon`, I get its name.

But now when I wish to make a new environment, I enter `$ mkvirtualenv wrk -p python3`, I get

```
ERROR: virtualenvwrapper could not find /home/pra-dan/.local/bin/virtualenv in your path
```

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 18.04, I have had the following:

```
usr/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader'` (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named virtualenvwrapper`)
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.
```

If Python could not import the module `virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader`,
check that `virtualenvwrapper` has been installed for
`VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3` and that PATH is
set properly.

```
sudo gedit .bashrc
```

It is how  `virtualenvwrapper` settings in `.bashrc` look like in my case:

```
export WORKON_HOME=~/.envs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
source ~/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

And I have done the following:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
sudo pip3 install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
source ~/.bashrc
```

That has helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed an important note in the instructions: the export lines need to come before sourcing virtualenvwrapper.sh.  You're sourcing virtualenvwrapper.sh twice.

Comment: It doesn't work @brian

Comment: Edited my answer, you need the exports before the sourcing of virtualenvwrapper.sh per the instructions.

Comment: I corrected my `.bashrc` and the above question but still have the problem after sourcing it

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that the python path provided in

```bsh
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
```

is same as the python path where you installed virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper.

To find your python path, use `which python` or, `which python3` command in console.

Also verify that either `python` or `python3` command in terminal triggers a python IDLE of the desired version.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 20.04 focal `which python` yields nothing, whereas `which python3` does. However `/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` relies on `which python`:

```
# Locate the global Python where virtualenvwrapper is installed.
if [ "${VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON:-}" = "" ]
then
    VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON="$(command \which python)"
fi
```

So you may edit the latter file with `sudo` and change `which python` to `which python3` or add an `export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3` (or any value shown by `which python3`) at the top of your home's `.bashrc file`.

Then to install `virtualenvwrapper` (for current user), run:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

Create a new terminal or log out/log in again to ensure the message has disappeared.